# Using make to build a 64 bit version of a program for C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile

I'm currently a student, and I am supposed to build a program from a lot of source files / plugins that I've installed. The final step in order to actually build the program is running a central makefile.

The problem is, I get this error towards the end: `ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _what0_: stack subq instruction is too different from dwarf stack size` and the build fails.

I'm currently on OSX 10.9.5, and my friend never had this issue when building his version of the same program. The TA to the class told me the reason it wouldn't build was because: "I was building it as 32 bit instead of 64 bit." And to solve this I needed to do one of two things:

1. Use a 64 bit version of the xCode tool chain instead of the 32 bit one.
2. Provide the proper option during compilation in order to emit x86_64 code.

After doing some researching, I'm not sure how I could install a 64bit version of the toolchain, since my xCode is 64 bit. And for the second one, I wasn't able to find any command to compile as x86_64 within the makefile.

Is there some easy way to accomplish this? I'm not even sure where else I could post this.. so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround could be to silence the linker warning. I don't see any option to suppress the warning about compact unwind. There seems to be only an option to enable the warning (`-warn_compact_unwind`). What you could do is to suppress all linker warnings passing `-Wl,-w` option to compiler.

Another temporary solution you could try is passing `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind` to clang. It should instruct the linker not to generate compact unwind information.

Regarding your question about compiling for 64 bit architecture. You specify the architecture with `-arch` compiler option – in your case `-arch x86_64`.